# PHP Function - cleaning up numbers with .00

Tags: php, function

I have a quick question.  I have a function like this:

```
function clean_num($num){
    return trim(trim($num, '0'), '.');
}
```

So when I have numbers like **85.00** and **55.00** it takes off the .00 and just returns **85** and **55**.

Well I have a number 0.00 and what happens is it is returning blank.  It should just say **0** but I am not getting a result at all.

How can I modify this function to get what I am looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`trim()` works on both ends. To only trim on the right end, use `rtrim()`.

```
function clean_num($num){
    return rtrim(rtrim($num, '0'), '.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`trim()` strips characters of *both* ends of the string. Try [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) instead:

```
function clean_num($num){
    return rtrim(rtrim($num, '0'), '.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple ([demo](http://www.ideone.com/ud8b6)):

```
function clean_num($num){
    return round($num, 2);
}
```

Or ([demo](http://www.ideone.com/Ms2nS)):

```
function clean_num($num){
    return rtrim(rtrim($num, '0'), '.');
}
```

Or even ([demo](http://www.ideone.com/3ZdJC)):

```
function clean_num($num){
    return preg_replace('~[.]0+$~', '', $num);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to eliminate decimals all together:

```
function clean($n) {
    return round($n);
}
```